# Unexpected behavior for a particular input

Tags: c++, while-loop, printf, continue, exponential

I have written the following code to find out the value in the **unit place** of the exponentiation **a^b** (http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/). It is working fine for all the test cases, except when **a=1**. When a=1, then it starts printing the output (i.e., 1) infinitely, on the command prompt (not on the online editors though). Also, this unexpected behavior is shown only if the input is as below:
1
1 (any number here as the exponent)
and not when:
1
(any number other than 1) (any number here as the exponent).

The code is as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if(a==1){               //Although a==1 the continue statement behaves abnormally
        printf("1\n");
        continue;
    }
    printf("Hello man 2! :)\n");
    int end=1,i,unit[500],temp=1;
    long long b;
    scanf("%lld",&b);
    if(b==0){
        printf("1\n");
        continue;
    }
    unit[0]=1;          
    bool goOn=true,marker=false;
    while(goOn){
        temp*=a;
        for(i=0; i<end; i++){
            if(unit[i]==(temp%10) && (temp%10)!=1)
                marker=true;
        }
        if(marker)
            goOn=false;
        if(!marker){
            unit[end]=(temp%10);
            end++;
        }
    }

    int tmp=b%(end-1);
    if(tmp==0)
        printf("%d\n",unit[(end-1)]);
    else
        printf("%d\n",unit[(tmp)]);
}
return 0;
}
```

What might be causing this abnormal behavior and how do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
I checked the code, and it works fine. As you have pointed out, this error only occurs on command prompt and not on online editors, a possible reason may be your compiler. Which one do you use? Or maybe you could provide some other details.

I have attached a screenshot below of it working in my terminal. Just for reference, I am using gcc version 4.9.1.

EDIT: I now wrote the output to a file. It still didn't present any issues. I need more information from you. On the lighter side, did you try turning the computer off and on again?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @therainmaker. I'm using gcc too. When I tried to export the answer to a .txt file, then it went on printing 1 infinitely in it. What might be the possible reason?

Comment: @abhishek_naik. I have edited the answer in response to your comment. Unfortunately, I am still unable to diagnose the issue. I need more information from your side.

Comment: it seems that simply restarting the command prompt and the machine did the trick. Thanks! Do you think it might have been because I had kept the PC running since a very long time and trying this example over and over again? Also, I tried resubmitting the solution, but its still a WA. :(

Comment: Haha. I guess I did correctly answer the question by saying turn it off and switch it on again. As for the suspected cause, what you say may have some weight to it, but I lack the knowledge to say anything for sure. Also, for the question, keep trying. That's always much better than someone else giving you the correct code.